# Check when fb-like is finish loading

Tags: jquery, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a [page](http://test.2send.co.il/Products/%D7%A2%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D) with list of products. for each product in the list I have fb-like item.

When the page contain many products it takes the fb-like element few second to finish loading, at this time I am displaying a modal-Popup.

Now I am using this code to wait 5 seconds to allow the fb-likes to load in the background:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            $("#mdlPopup").hide();
        } catch (ex) { }
    },
        5000);  
});
```

It would be ideal to check if all the fb-like items are loaded and then to hide the modal-popup.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind load handler of FB iframes

```
$(function () {
     var fbDone = 0;
    $(document).on('load','.fb_ltr',function () {
        fbDone++;
        if (fbDone === $('.fb_ltr').length) $("#mdlPopup").hide();
    })
});
```

**EDIT**

Looks like a moderator has removed all comments.

Maybe try to add just ajaxStop handler to document:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#mdlPopup_backgroundElement").show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#mdlPopup_backgroundElement").hide();
});
```